# Can a piece of conductor be made invisible to radar by overdamping?

Tags: rf-electronics, radar

To my understanding every conductor reemits a bit of electromagnetic waves induced in it by radiation.

If theres a way in an antenna one could create a wave of opposite phase to the incident one so that there's no net oscillating field, could it make it invisible to radar?

Comment: The primary method of going stealthy is to remove all retro-corners (gaps, holes) and to build your gadget out of flat plates, since unless a flat plate is exactly perpendicular to the radar wave direction, nothing will be reflected back to the source receiver.  There's a good chapter on this in "Skunk Works,"  by Ben Rich.

Answer (score 1):

this can be done my matching the electromagnetic impedance of the material to that of free air. By using dissipative elements (ohmic resistance) in the material to match impedances, the radar waves will be absorbed and dissipated, generating almost no reflection and thereby making the object invisible to radar. This is the fundamental principle of stealth materials.

Comment: This is true only for single-point radar.  If you have the xmtr and rcvr at different locations, "stealth" absorbers will appear as a hole in the signal & the object thus easily detected.